# Growth condition for Ito diffusions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Given a one-dimensional SDE 
$$
\begin{cases}
dX_t &= b(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dB_t,
\\
X_0 &= Z
\end{cases}
$$ 
for $t\in[0,T]$ where $Z$ is square integrable: $\mathsf E[Z^2]<\infty$ the sufficient conditions for existence and uniqueness are: *the growth condition*
$$
|b(t,x)|+|\sigma(t,x)|\leq C(1+|x|)\quad\forall x\in \mathbb R, t\in [0,T]
$$
and *the Lipschitz condition*
$$
|b(t,x'')-b(t,x')|+|\sigma(t,x'')-\sigma(t,x')|\leq D|x''-x'|\quad\forall x',x''\in \mathbb R.
$$
These conditions are stated e.g. in Theorem 5.2.1, "Stochastic Differential Equations" (p. 68 [here](http://books.google.nl/books?id=kXw9hB4EEpUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

However, in the definition of an Ito diffusion as a process satisfying
$$
dX_t = b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t
$$
for $t\geq s$, where $X_s = x$, in the same book (p. 114 on the linked webpage) it is written that conditions simplify to Lipschitz condition. Could you help me to understand the reasoning of that?

Comment: @sos440: thank you - would you put this as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's consider a simplest case: Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy global Lipschitz condition

$$ |f(x) - f(y)| \leq L |x - y|, \quad x, y \in \mathbb{R}$$

with Lipschitz constant $L$. Then by triangle inequality, we have

$$ |f(x)| \leq |f(x) - f(0)| + |f(0)| \leq L|x| + |f(0)| \leq C(|x| + 1)$$

for large $C \geq \max(L, |f(0)|)$. Same argument applies to this case.