# Literature for SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

I have good knowledge about stochastic analysis without SDE and I search for literature which explains basic definitions, existence and uniqueness results for SDEs like

$$
dX_t=\mu\left(t,X_t\right)\ dt+\sigma\left(t,X_t\right)\ dB_t.
$$

with $t \in [0,T]$.

I am looking for a result that we have a unique solutions if the coefficients are locally Lipschitz with linear growth.

Does anybody know good literature for this?

I am sorry for the not precise description of the SDE, but I don't know the exact requirements.

Comment: I believe such a result is found in Oksendal's book.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113919/growth-condition-for-ito-diffusions?rq=1

Comment: Ikeda and Watanabe's _Stochastic Differential equations and Diffusion Processes_ is a classical reference for SDEs and has some good existence and uniqueness results.

Comment: That would be Karatzas and Shreve's book for me Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some books

- Shreve-Karatzas "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus"
- Revuz-Yor "Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion"
- Stroock-Varadhan "Multidimensional Diffusion Processes"