# Stratonovich SDE and main hint for Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I've stuck on a SDE problem. Namely, I've got to solve equation
$$
\text{d}X_t = e^{-X_t}\circ\text{d}B_t.
$$
So in order to apply Ito's lemma, I transformed this SDE into form
$$
\text{d}X_t = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-2X_t}\text{d}t +  e^{-X_t}\text{d}B_t.
$$
I don't have any clue how to pick the proper function to apply Ito's lemma on. Is there any some sort of scheme of picking such functions on various SDEs? Moreover, I would love to get some hints about the literature with some of SDEs examples, solving techniques and applications.

Answer (score 0):

For $Y_{t}=e^{2X_{t}}$ we get

$$dY_{t}=Y_{t}dB_{t}$$

and so as mentioned [Solution to General Linear SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde), we get

$$Y_{t}=Y_0\exp\left( \int_0^t\left(- \frac{1}{2}s^{2} \right) \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t s\mathrm{d}B_s\right).$$

I picked a function that would lead to cancelations i.e. $e^{2X_{t}}e^{-2X_{t}}=1$.

Comment: Thanks!, also, have you got any literature to recommend?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4270608/literature-for-sde